# Countdown JS+PHP, what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, countdown

I'm trying to make this function work but i don't know what's wrong and i'm not really good at js.
I want to do call my timer function with number of seconds to countdown from the span id "count".

Example:

```
<p id="hello">Wait <span id="count">5</span> secs</p>

<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , 'timer(5);'
   , '</script>';
?>
<script>
function timer(tiempo){

  setInterval(function() {
    tiempo--;
    if (tiempo >= 0) {
      span = document.getElementById("count");
      span.innerHTML = tiempo;
    }
    // Display 'counter' wherever you want to display it.
    if (tiempo === 0) {
      window.location.reload();
        clearInterval(tiempo);
    }

  }, 1000);

});
</script>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: timer is not definedxfantasy.php:306 (anonymous function)

Comment: Remove the parentyses around `(function timer(){[...]})()`. You end up with `function timer(){[...]}` only

Comment: Removed parentyses and got same error.

Comment: Then put the PHP code **after** the `function timer{[...]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the function before it's called:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function timer(tiempo){
  setInterval(function() {
    tiempo--;
    if (tiempo >= 0) {
      span = document.getElementById("count");
      span.innerHTML = tiempo;
    }
    // Display 'counter' wherever you want to display it.
    if (tiempo === 0) {
      window.location.reload();
        clearInterval(tiempo);
    }

  }, 1000);

}
</script>
<p id="hello">Wait <span id="count">5</span> secs</p>

<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , 'timer(5);'
   , '</script>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here has nothing to do with the PHP.

In JavaScript in an HTML document:

- Function declarations are hoisted
- All scripts share the same working environment

However:

- Functions are not hoisted from a later script to an earlier script

---

You are running a script that tries to run the timer function.

Then you are running a script that defines that function.

It doesn't exist in time.

Either:

- Swap the order of the `<script>` elements **or**
- Remove the first `</script>` tag and the second `<script>` tag

Answer (score 0):

**Check the demo.**

**HTML**

```
<p id="hello">Wait <span id="count">5</span> secs</p>
<input type="button" value="start" id="start" />
```

**Jquery and JS**

```
$('#start').click(function(){
showTimer(5);
});

function showTimer(tiempo){

    setInterval(function() {
    tiempo--;
    if (tiempo >= 0) {
      span = document.getElementById("count");
        span.innerHTML = tiempo+'.....';
    }
    // Display 'counter' wherever you want to display it.
    if (tiempo === 0) {
     // window.location.reload();
        clearInterval(tiempo);
        alert('movie starts......');
    }

  }, 1000);

}
```

**DEMO**

```
http://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/jeps93gy/
```